# graph to find shortest path to origin using nodes I visited

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, path-finding

Given the directions and a route, I want to know the shortest path to, in the end, get back to where I started(origin) only using places I have visited before

(example of the image below, N is north, S south etc)

Sample Input :
NNEEEENWNENNSEEEWWWSWSESWWWNNNNWWWSSNNNNEE

Sample Output :
14

[image with example, red is shortest path and gives the 14 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdy53.png)

I am working in java and want to use a Breadth-First Search algorithm and want to use a graph, which is the best way I can construct this graph and look a this problem?

Can someone help?

Comment: It occurs to me that if each square contained a list of "arrival" objects with the direction one had come from and the number of steps taken to get there, the shortest route back could be found by always reversing the course arrived by with the fewest steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a graph of visited cells by reading the input and then run a BFS on this graph from the last position.

To generate the graph you can do :

```
for each direction :
   create node for the cell if not already existing
   for each adjacent cell, if visited then connect them together
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run a BFS, starting from the end and going to positions you have already passed, stopping once you reach the origin position:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int m[9][10];
int v[9][10];

struct point{
    int x, y, dist;
    point(){}
    point(int x, int y){this->x = x; this->y = y; dist = 0;}
    point(int x, int y, int dist){this->x = x; this->y = y; this->dist = dist;}
    bool operator == (const point &rhs) const { return rhs.x == x && rhs.y == y; }
};

point origin(2, 8);
point target(2, 0);

int BFS(){
    queue<point> q;
    q.push(target);
    while(!q.empty()){
        point p = q.front();
        q.pop();
        v[p.y][p.x] = 1;
        if(p == origin) return p.dist;

        if(p.x > 0 && !v[p.y][p.x - 1] && m[p.y][p.x - 1]) q.push(point(p.x - 1, p.y, p.dist + 1)); //left
        if(p.x < 9 && !v[p.y][p.x + 1] && m[p.y][p.x + 1]) q.push(point(p.x + 1, p.y, p.dist + 1)); //right
        if(p.y > 0 && !v[p.y - 1][p.x] && m[p.y - 1][p.x]) q.push(point(p.x, p.y - 1, p.dist + 1)); //up
        if(p.y < 8 && !v[p.y + 1][p.x] && m[p.y + 1][p.x]) q.push(point(p.x, p.y + 1, p.dist + 1)); //down
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(){
    memset(m, 0, sizeof(m));
    memset(v, 0, sizeof(v));
    m[origin.y][origin.x] = 1;

    string path = "NNEEEENWNENNSEEEWWWSWSESWWWNNNNWWWSSNNNNEE";

    point o(origin.x, origin.y);

    for(int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++){
        if(path[i] == 'N') o.y--;
        else if(path[i] == 'S') o.y++;
        else if(path[i] == 'W') o.x--;
        else if(path[i] == 'E') o.x++;
        m[o.y][o.x] = 1;
    }

    cout<<"dist = "<<BFS()<<endl;
}
```

**OUTPUT: dist = 14**.